# Genymotion and React-native

Tags: installation, react-native, genymotion

I am developing react native apps for one month.I am getting this error in galaxy 6.0.0 at initial state in genymotion.

```
Unfortunately app has stopped
```

can anyone how to solve this problem?

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: I am sorry I did not  know how to check the logs I'm this for now
     adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V

Comment: There's a ui for it. Navigate to `YOUR_ANDROID_SDK/tools/` and then run `monitor`.

Comment: @Zidail  thanks i'll try this and get back here

Comment: @Zidail I'm getting this error

04-18 06:09:57.088: E/GMPM(2074): getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
04-18 06:09:57.091: E/GMPM(2074): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

04-18 06:09:58.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 06:09:58.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): Process: com.smilesettai, PID: 2074
04-18 06:09:58.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2074): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 94MB until OOM
04-18 06:09:58.428: E/AndroidRuntime(2074):

Comment: Try upping the memory of your simulator. Also make sure that Google Play Services/Analytics is properly initialized. Looks like you might need to enable `App measurements` in the Google console.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should debug your app using [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html). And then see and solve the error (os post here if you need help to solve).